# prototype : registry is undefined

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have  registry is undefined row: 5557...with prototype 1.7.

```
$$('#pageNav a').each(function(element) {
    element.observe('click', doSome(this.href));
})
```

pageNav is a UL list with LI and A tags.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but what is `this` referring to? Try `element.href`.

Answer (score 7):

This may not apply exactly, but I had a very similar problem.  Turned out the object I was trying to attach an event handler to was undefined.

```
// objTbl is undefined -> 'registry is undefined' error
Event.observe(objTbl.rows[i], 'mousedown', getClick);error
```

I'm guessing this type of error will usually come back to the object or the handling function being undefined.